# Complex EF query return base objects but filtering on child objects

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

1. I have a class called Query.
2. And I have a class Called Permissions
3. Query has a Collection of Permissions
4. I need to query the Queries for which a user has a permission.

but I am not sure how to make the where clause.

```
public class Query
{
    public int QueryId { get; set; }
    public string QueryName { get; set; }
    public string QuerySql { get; set; }
    public string CreatedBy { get; set; }
    public string QueryType { get; set; }
    public string Column1 { get; set; }
    public string Operator1 { get; set; }
    public string Value1 { get; set; }
    public string Connector2 { get; set; }
    public string Column2 { get; set; }
    public string Operator2 { get; set; }
    public string Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Connector3 { get; set; }
    public string Column3 { get; set; }
    public string Operator3 { get; set; }
    public string Value3 { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Permission>  Permissions { get; set; }
}

public class Permission
{
    public int PermissionId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
}

public IQueryable<Query> GetQueriesForUser(string userName)
{
    _context.Queries.Where(m=>m.Permissions.Contains(???))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you want all the queries
where there is a permission for that query
where the username of the permission is the username of the user

You could use something like:

```
_context.Queries.Where(q => q.Permissions.Any(p => p.UserName.Equals(userName)));
```